# Padding around text in android spinner

Tags: android

Оk guуs, here is the problem:
There are two spinners on the layout. First spinner is totally OK when second one's sections are thin.
How to make it standard sized like on second screenshot?

Here are screenshots and XML:

[image]
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Currency"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_currency">

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/spinner3"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner4"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Convert"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:onClick="Convert"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?? do you want add space between borders?? or decrease the size of the spinner? please elobarate

Comment: The layout of the items in a spinner are defined by the adapter. If helps to see the java code used to populate the spinners.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.
I want spinner items with text to look like they do on second screenshot. I assume it is right to call this size "standard size"